# Selenium with Python: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a Web Scraping script using Python (rev. 3.8) and Selenium, Firefox and geckodriver (all latest versions).

I need to select an Item from a dropdown list. My Problem: when I try to select an Item I get the following message:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view`

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

url = 'https://www.hessen-forst.de/marktplatz/#brennholz'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\\Program Files\\geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id("nf-field-166")))

element = driver.find_element_by_id("nf-field-166")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("nf-field-166"))

print(len(select.options))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

select.select_by_visible_text("Nidda")
```

the `print(len(select.options))` line gives me the correct number of instances I expect. Printing the options names with `print(select.obtions[i].text)` also gives correct results. Therefor I expect the right drop-down-list was selected.

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)` brings the drop-down-list in the center of the Browser-Window for a fraction of a second, with `select.select_by_visible_text("Nidda")` the drop-down-list is slightly below the visible area.

I have already tryed the *WebDriverWait*: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='nf-field-166']//options[contains(.,'Nidda')]")))`. Here the Result is a Timeout.

Using `select_by_value` gives the same error.

Can you help me with another idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Using chrome browser it is absolutely working fine with `select()` method. I am not sure if this is the problem with FF browser? Can you try with  chrome browser?

Comment: You are absolutely right, no Problem in Chrome-Browser. Thank you!!